Can you use All You Can Fly with Privilege Pass to get cheap travels with free trolley bag each time?
Yesterday WizzAir launched new pass for 500 EUR/year, which allows you to fly for a fixed fee of 10 EUR for each booking (starting late September)

This pass doesn't decently-sized cabin bag (only standard 40x30x20 which is really small), and while it's stated you can purchase wizz priority/baggage separately while booking your flight, it still usually costs a lot and would defeat the whole purpose of dirt cheap travels with All You Can Fly pass.

However, there exists Privilege Pass which allows you to bring a free trolley bag on board:

The question is, can you combine All You Can Fly with Privilege Pass, to get flights of 10EUR each without the need of paying for the big bag? I haven't been able to find an explicit info on this topic

Have you read Wizzair's General Conditions of Carriage? These are the contract terms that apply when a ticket is purchased. I haven't read it, but I'd not be surprised that somewhere in tiny type is a statement that only one "special offer" (or some other phrase) may be used for a given leg or trip or even only a single passenger on one occasion.
